# Joomla issue adding id selector

Tags: html, css, joomla

By template.css I can add style to an html element of an article with attribute class, but if I try to use attribute id template.css seems doesn't see this id in html

```
<div id="cellsx " style="color: #ffffff; padding-right: 10px; padding-left: 10px; width:   90%;">
```

Comment: So, you're saying that `#cellsx {}` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, while if I insert class="cellsx" , .cellsx{} works perfectly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance, there shouldn't be a space within the `id` attribute.

```
<div id="cellsx "></div>
               ^ remove this
```

In doing so, you should be able to use `#cellsx {}`

See this [**example here**](http://jsfiddle.net/JoshC/JCPb6/), demonstrating the difference.